# Weird Each Function in Jquery executing twice when code loaded with load

Tags: jquery

I have a code that loops with a jQuery each. If you run the code with

https://jsfiddle.net/q3zL6vba/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var res=''

$('button').click(function(){
var tr = '<tr class="quoterow"><input class="in" type="hidden" value="xxx"><td class="first">C</td><td class="second">D <button class="remove">remove</button></td></tr>';
$('table').append(tr);  

$('button.remove').click(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
go();
});

go();
});



function go(){

var c=0;

$('.quoterow').each(function(){ 

c++;

});
alert(c)
}



$('div').click(function(){
$('.quoterow').each(function(){ 

res = res + "<li>";
res = res + $(this).find('.first').html();
res = res + " AND ";
res = res + $(this).find('.second').html();
res = res + $(this).find('.in').val();
$('div').html(res);

});
});


});
```

it works but if I put that code into a page and then I load that page code with the jquery load function the result is that the each function **is executed 2 times.**

This is weird as the number of element is correct it only look like the each function runs 2 times.

By the way, jquery is loaded only from the parent page.

Any idea is welcome. I don't understand why this happens or might happen.

I tried to add a control to see if the go function is called twice but that's not the case

```
var Looped = false; 
    
function go(){
    
if(Looped) alert('loop');
    
$('.quoterow').each(function(){
    
...

});
Looped=true;
}
```

Also tried with vanilla code and the result is the same. But where is the ghost code I can't read in console log, but this javascript is reading twice?

```
var YYP = document.querySelectorAll(".quoterow");

for(var i = 0; i < YYP.length; i++) {
        
}

alert(i);
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation (and use a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: why do you think, functions run 2 times and which function ?

Comment: $('.quoterow').each - it looks like it reads duplicated tr tags with this class but the page does not have duplicated tags that can be read in a loop. I have inspected the code and there s apparently no reason for that.

Comment: I there a way to make sure the each function is executed only once? it would help get the reason.

Comment: I tried to add a control to see if the go function is called twice but that's not the case

Comment: Any other way to debug the each function that is going crazy?

Comment: Why ```$('button.remove')``` inside the button click function? - just cleaning up a little...

Comment: well, ofcourse, if you click the add button you have a second , third <tr class="quoterow">, nevertheless to get amount of elements, you can use : var lnCount = $('.quoterow').length;
alert('count'+ lnCount);

Comment: lnCount counts double like the each function. Where can jquery get elements that are not in the code. I'm sure about the code I put a console.log($('tablet').html()) and this is perfect, there are no extra tr, nor other elements with the same class.

Comment: Also tried with vanilla code and the result is the same. But where is the ghost code I can't read in console log, but this javascript is reading twice? See modified question.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the problem is coming up due to loading the code from the parent page with load('page.html) where page html includes the code I have. It does not make sense if you have any idea o something to explore more please let me know.

Comment: Solved the problem was in the div where I loaded the external page that had the same class of another div and this caused duplicated contents

Comment: @rosia can you post your answer please